# exporting oracle tables on command line as sql files

Tags: oracle, export

I use exp and expdp to export database tables on command line but it generates binary **.dmp** files. I want to export/import tables as **.sql*** files **on command line** like pl/sql developer app can do. Is there a specific command for this or extra parameters for exp/expdp?

*sql files must contain table creation scripts and insert statements.

Thanks.

Comment: No, you'd need to write your own extract scripts. You can get the DDL with the `dbms_metadata` package, but you'll need to generate your own insert statements. (Or find an automated dynamic example on the 'net somewhere). What's wrong with a binary dump file though?

Comment: hi @AlexPoole i need to track code changes on git, i always export it from pl/sql developer but i need automation...

Comment: Well, [here's a list of reasons this isn't simple](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8600685/266304), and [here's Tom Kyte's view](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:759825200346294209); that has some attempts at generating the statements dynamically, but I'd be very careful about checking anything you find like this works for all your data *8-)

Comment: oh i see... It seems very tricky and error-prone

Comment: I'd also suggest this sounds backwards. You seem to want the schema and data in your database to be the 'master'. It would be simpler to keep your DDL and DML (presumably for initial base data) statements in files that you maintain outside the database, and check those in; and make changes to your DB using those files. Making ad hoc changes and then trying to track them afterwards sounds painful. But, just my opinion of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate DDL statements using imp/impdp utilities:

```
imp user/passwd file=export.dmp show=y log=export.sql 2> /dev/null
impdp user/passwd file=DIR:export.expdp sqlfile=DIR:export2.sql
```

But this method will generate just schema DDL. INSERT statements will not be generated.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently had almost the same need, so I have written a simple script to create insert statements. It is located at [github](https://github.com/ReneNyffenegger/oracle_scriptlets/blob/master/sqlpath/insert_statement_creator.sql). However, the script does not create the table creation statements. You should use `dbms_metadata` for this.